# Bootstrap mobile navigation collpased

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys i use bootstrap (the latest version given),but the navigation has collapsed on mobile view.Please can any help me out.
my website http://mywebsyt.net63.net/

here is my html code:

```
     <header class="navbar-inverse" role="banner">
     <div class=container>
     <nav role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-   example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li> <a href="http://mywebsyt.net63.net/">Home</a>  </li>
                   <?php
                    if (AuthUser::isLoggedIn(false))
                    {
                        //logged in 
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_url('admin/') . '">' . __('Panel') . '</a></li>
                            <li><a href="' . get_url('login/logout/') . '">' . __('Log out') . '</a></li>
                            <li><a href="' . get_url('index/upload/') . '">' . __('Upload') . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_url('login/') . '">' . __('Login') . '</a></li>
                            <li><a href="' . get_url('index/upload/') . '">' . __('Upload') . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo  get_url('h/') ?>"><?php echo __('Trending') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo  get_url('d/') ?>"><?php echo __('Popular') ?></a> 
        <li><a href="<?php echo  get_url('r/') ?>"><?php echo __('Rated') ?></a> </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You code looks ok. I think you should try to update your jQuery to latest version. It was too old v1.5 it should be above v1.8 i think. Try after updating.

Comment: Thank you for replying.Im new to this field.Can you please tell me how can i update to the latest Jquery..

Comment: just download the latest version in jquery.com and replace it with your jquery file.

Comment: You will find "<script src="http://mywebsyt.net63.net/public/js/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" in your head tag. Remove it and replace it with "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" or download from "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" and replace your js file.

Comment: thank you.. but then now too it doesnt work i  updated to 1.11.0

Comment: There is some problem with website. error shows "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" so jQuery is not included yet. please check once again.